# how to hook drawRect() to a subView that view have created it programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've create a subview using following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect subviewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
    mysubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subviewRect];
    [mysubview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:mysubview];
}
```

and I want to draw some graphics in this sub view , so I think I need to access to its drawRect function but how can I hook `drawRect()` to mysubview programmatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subviewRect];
```

Should be

```
mysubview = [[AustinPowersView alloc] initWithFrame:subviewRect];
```

Where `AustinPowersView` is a subclass of `UIView`, in which you have overridden `drawRect:`

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass UIView and override its drawRect: method.

Although Apple states

> Implement this method if your view draws custom content. If your view
>   does not do any custom drawing, avoid overriding this method.

So if you have just "normal" UIKit interface elements to add to it, you should just add them as subviews and let the view take care of its drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't subclassing `UIView` and overwriting `-drawRect:` in there not do the trick?